# Android hide bottom navigation bar like in youtube app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-animation, bottomnavigationview

I am working on hiding the google bottomNavigationView I tried using visibility, there is a flicker. How to hide the android bottom navigation once user select an nested item,  I need something like that uses in youtube app that slides when video fragment shown.

```
fun hideBottomNav() {
   bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.GONE
}
    
fun showBottomNav() {
    bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

Used the below link that was sliding still flicker and most of the time the view was not hiding/showing as expected.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62955506/8775993

And also used the translate animation that also not working that good.

Need help in hiding or showing view without flicker's and smoother animation. Anyone can help?

Comment: Have you tried ViewPropertyAnimator? -> bottomNavigationView.animate().translationXBy(...) should slide left or right, depending on your ... values

Comment: Tried that also but nope it will have some glitch issue