# How to Hide Bottom Bar Nav.. When following single Activity design?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

I am trying to show thebottom bar navigation in only a few fragments (i.e hide it for most of my fragments)..

I read the [official document](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#listen_for_navigation_events) about this, but it unclear to me, like where do I put the code, and I read [comments on this here on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61626461), like "*I'm surprised this is suggested in the docs because it actually looks pretty terrible since the listener fires before the new fragment is placed on the screen, causing a visible flicker (that's sometimes there, sometimes not)*".

I've research about this, and from my understanding I need to create a nested naviagtion_graph (navigation), or something, listen to onDestinationChanged and set bottom nav or toolbar to Gone..

I don't really understand this.. I just want to hide the bottom bar nav in most of the fragments..

Here's my navigation_gragh (`mobile_navigation`) :

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.example.testingbottomnav.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_home_to_newScreenFragment"
            app:destination="@id/newScreenFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="com.example.testingbottomnav.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:name="com.example.testingbottomnav.ui.notifications.NotificationsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_notifications"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notifications" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/newScreenFragment"
        android:name="com.example.testingbottomnav.ui.newscreen.NewScreenFragment"
        android:label="fragment_new_screen"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_new_screen" />
</navigation>
```

Here's my `activity_main.xml` :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here's my `MainActivty.kt` :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this line of code to the onCreate method:

```
// hiding bottom bar
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, nd: NavDestination, _ ->
        // the IDs of fragments as defined in the `navigation_graph`
        if (nd.id == R.id.navigation_home || nd.id == R.id.navigation_dashboard
            || nd.id == R.id.navigation_notifications
        ) {
            navView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            navView.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to make visible your `BottomNavigationView` only if the destination is the top-level destination you can try:

```
 val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, 
                R.id.navigation_dashboard, 
                R.id.navigation_notifications
            )
        )
 navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller: NavController, destination: NavDestination, bundle: Bundle? ->
 yourBottomNavigationView.isVisible = appBarConfiguration.topLevelDestinations.contains(destination.id)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*First set up your navigation after that add a destination change listener to the nav controller. Whenever you navigate to a fragment `navController.navigate(/* Some Destination Id */)`  the destination change listener will fire up there you can check and compare if you want to show or hide the bottom navigation or toolbar.*

```
private fun setupBottomNavigation() {

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container_view) as NavHostFragment?

        if (navHostFragment != null) {

            navController = navHostFragment.navController

            setupWithNavController(binding!!.navView, navController!!)

            initDestinationListener()

        }
    }

    private fun initDestinationListener() {

        navController!!.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller: NavController?, destination: NavDestination, bundle: Bundle? ->

            // Showing or Hiding Bottom Navigation on Specific Screen
            
            if (destination.id == R.id.navigation_plan ||
                destination.id == R.id.navigation_video ||
                destination.id == R.id.navigation_about ||
                destination.id == R.id.navigation_detail ||
                destination.id == R.id.navigation_contact ||
                destination.id == R.id.navigation_privacy ||
                destination.id == R.id.navigation_comments
            ) {

                hideBottomNavigation()

            } else {

                showBottomNavigation()

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Malik.. But what are the "R.id.navigation_plan" and others, are they fragment I want to hide the bottom bar nav??

Comment: @Edwin they are the ids of the fragments in the navigation graph. If you want to hide bottom navigation on a fragment add their id to the if condition.

Comment: I'm getting an unresolved error for hideBottomNavigation() and showBottomNavigation().. How do I correct this please..

Comment: Thanks a lot Malik for your help, I have been able to resolved the issue..

Answer (score 2):

you can write a method to init the navigation in your activity and hide navigation in this method and use it in onCreate() like this:

```
 private fun setupNavigation() {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
        when (destination.id) {
            R.id.fragment1 -> bottomNavigation.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            R.id.fragment2 -> bottomNavigation.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            R.id.fragment3 -> bottomNavigation.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            else -> bottomNavigation.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
}
```

this code show navigation in fragment 1 ,2 ,3 and hide it for another fragment

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to fix this is to create a method in your MainActivity which allows you to show/hide the BottomNavigationView. Open the MainActivity.kt class and add the following methods to it.

```
fun showBottomNavigation()
{
    bottomNavView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}

fun hideBottomNavigation()
{
    bottomNavView.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Now, call these methods from the Fragment you want to hide BottomNavigationView like this.

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    (activity as MainActivity).hideBottomNavigation()
}

override fun onDetach() {
    (activity as MainActivity).showBottomNavigation()
    super.onDetach()
}
```

Comment: +1. Worked. I put them on `onStart` instead. Also, if you have FAB button in BottomNavigationView, hide it like BottomNavigationView.