# how do I make the bottom navbar not appear in certain fragments ? Android Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

I have only 1 activity in my project and fragments are shown through one navigation . How do I make my bottom navbar show only in certain fragments?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to hide BottomNavigationView on android-navigation lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087740/how-to-hide-bottomnavigationview-on-android-navigation-lib)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the visibility based on navigation destination

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
   if(destination.id == R.id.fragment1) {
       
       bottomNavbar.visibility = View.GONE
   } else {
       
       bottomNavbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
   }
}
```